# Converting Bitmap to a vector of unsigned char

Tags: c++, gdi+

As the title says, I'm trying to find a method of converting a GDI+ Bitmap to a vector of unsigned chars, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use CreateStreamOnHGlobal() to get an IStream that you can pass to the Save() method.  Avoiding copying the bytes into the vector is going to require your own IStream implementation.

Comment: Saving to file isn't the goal he wants to copy the bytes into a vector in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`Bitmap::LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536298(v=vs.85).aspx). Once you've locked the bits, it should be trivial to copy them to a `vector<unsigned char>`. Better yet, resize the vector to the required size and let LockBits copy directly to it.